# Searchbar transition only to the right

Tags: css

I would like to use this searchbar, but need the
transition was only to the right side, is possible to do it
completely with css?
[searchbar](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/GaeQR)

Answer (score 0):

The container has `display: flex` applied and `justify-content: center`. Remove the `justify-content-center` from the class names. Here's a snippet:

```css
    body,html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #e74c3c !important;
    }

    .searchbar{
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #353b48;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    .search_input{
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: none;
    width: 0;
    caret-color:transparent;
    line-height: 40px;
    transition: width 0.4s linear;
    }

    .searchbar:hover > .search_input{
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 450px;
    caret-color:red;
    transition: width 0.4s linear;
    }

    .searchbar:hover > .search_icon{
    background: white;
    color: #e74c3c;
    }

    .search_icon{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Awesome Search Box</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <!-- Coded with love by Mutiullah Samim-->
  <body>
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="d-flex h-100">
        <div class="searchbar">
          <input class="search_input" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search...">
          <a href="#" class="search_icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```